# Extracting part of variable name for use in function

Tags: r, regex, function

I have an object, res_list, that contains data that I would like to extract using a function.

res_list$ has the following possibilities: Cearly,Rearly,Clate,Rlate,Cfollow,Rfollow.

I want to create a function to extract data from all the different res_list$ possibilities, in an iterative manner, by utilising the 'name' of data objects I have already created in R

The names of these objects are as follows:

```
signi_BTM_Cearly2
signi_BTM_Clate2
.
.
.
signi_BTM_Rfollow2
```

Basically, I just want to tell the function I am creating to take only the "Cearly", "Clate",..."Rfollow" part of the table names. So I can retrieve the data that I need.

I know its a very simple task, I just can't figure it out.

Thank you all for your time,

Comment: Try to wrap your samples in CODE TAGS `{}` button and try to select any one of the answer as correct answer to complete any thread, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following simple use of `gsub` may also help you here.

```
val3<-c("signi_BTM_Cearly2","signi_BTM_Clate2")
gsub(".*_|\\d+$","",val3)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[1] "Cearly2" "Clate2"
```

Comment: I think you need `gsub(".*_|\\d+$", "", val3)`

Comment: @akrun, ahh missed it, thanks for letting me know sir you ROCK, changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `sub` to capture the characters after the `_` as a group followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) at the end (`$`) of the string and replace by the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*_([A-Za-z]+)\\d+$", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "Cearly"  "Clate"   "Rfollow"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("signi_BTM_Cearly2", "signi_BTM_Clate2", "signi_BTM_Rfollow2")
```